# How to fix? variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization

I'm getting an error:

> return ***leastRainMonth***; variable might not have been initialized

How can I fix it?

```
public class Rainfall
{
   double [] rainfallNumber;

   public double getTotalRainfall() {
     double totalRainfall = 0;

     for (int index = 0; index < rainfallNumber.length; index++) {
         totalRainfall = totalRainfall+rainfallNumber[index];
        }
        return totalRainfall;
    }

    public double getAverageRainfall() {
        return getTotalRainfall() / rainfallNumber.length;
    }

    public int getMoreRainfallMonth() {
        double moreRain = rainfallNumber[0];
        int moreRainMonth = 1;

        for (int index = 0; index < rainfallNumber.length; index++) {
         if(rainfallNumber[index] > moreRain) {
             moreRain = rainfallNumber[index];
             moreRainMonth = index + 1;
            }
        }
        return moreRainMonth;
    }

    public int getLeastRainfallMonth() {
        double leastRain = rainfallNumber[0];
        int leastRainMonth;

        for (int index = 0; index < rainfallNumber.length; index++) {
         if(rainfallNumber[index] < leastRain) {
             leastRain = rainfallNumber[index];
             leastRainMonth = index + 1;
            }
        }
        return ***leastRainMonth***;
    }

   public Rainfall (double [] rainfallNumberGiven) {
       rainfallNumber = new double[rainfallNumberGiven.length];

       for (int index = 0; index < rainfallNumberGiven.length; index++) {
           rainfallNumber[index] = rainfallNumberGiven[index];  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatted code, moved error to be at the top, added tag

Answer (score 1):

Any time you initialize a variable in a loop that is declared outside the loop, you run the risk of the array size (or number of iterations) being zero, and therefore initialization is skipped. You can either:

1. Pick a default integer to initialize `leastRainMonth`
2. Change the return type of `getLeastRainfallMonth()` to `Integer` and initialize `Integer leastRainMonth = null;` (hassle).

In this case, you should probably do the first option and initialize `int leastRainMonth = 1;`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize leastRainMonth variable in its declaration as you do for moreRainMonth.